# How to separate JSON

Tags: apex

I want to get send mail to customer, in the body I have to add channelRefId, leadRefId, statusCode, statusCd values separately from response.

```
    {"body":{"statusDesc":"Failure : {\"errorMessages\":[\"leadOwnerId is mandatory\"]}","channelRefId":"","leadRefId":"","leadId":"SF190623017684","statusCode":"FF"},"head":{"statusCd":"100","txnID":"CRMPUSH_20230619123703_25023m"}}
```

I tried with

```
string res = '{"body":{"statusDesc":"Failure : {\"errorMessages\":[\"leadOwnerId is mandatory\"]}","channelRefId":"","leadRefId":"","leadId":"SF190623017684","statusCode":"FF"},"head":{"statusCd":"100","txnID":"CRMPUSH_20230619123703_25023m"}}';
Map<String, Object> m = 
   (Map<String, Object>)
      JSON.deserializeUntyped(res);

System.assertEquals(
   'An appliance', m.get('description'));
```

but not working.
Please let me know how to get above values from response.

Comment: Where are you doing this? In Apex? In LWC?

Comment: I need to use these use this in flow to send email temaplte

Comment: I have a field called response status updating with {"body":{"statusDesc":"Failure : {\"errorMessages\":[\"leadOwnerId is mandatory\"]}","channelRefId":"","leadRefId":"","leadId":"SF190623017684","statusCode":"FF"},"head":{"statusCd":"100","txnID":"CRMPUSH_20230619123703_25023m"}} i need to fetch separate fields in flow to send emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When declaring a String in Apex some characters need to be escaped with a backslash. Examples include ' and \ itself. So when declaring a String, `\'` means `'` and `\\` means `\`.

Your code needs to be as follows. (Note the double backslashes instead of single in the value of `statusDesc`)

```
String res = '{"body":{"statusDesc":"Failure : {\\"errorMessages\\":[\\"leadOwnerId is mandatory\\"]}","channelRefId":"","leadRefId":"","leadId":"SF190623017684","statusCode":"FF"},"head":{"statusCd":"100","txnID":"CRMPUSH_20230619123703_25023m"}}';

Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res);
```

Then, to get your values from the body:

```
Map<String, Object> b = (Map<String, Object>)m.get('body');

System.assertEquals('SF190623017684', b.get('leadId'));
```

Ideally, you would use typed deserialization instead, but untyped will still work.

Comment: Double quotes in apex do not need to be escaped inside strings. If you see this in JSON (as we do in OP's example) then that's an indication that something has been _double-serialized_. It's hard to say exactly what OP should do here (due to a general lack of detail), but if this is really just a string with literal JSON (and it's not coming from somewhere else) then one of the steps here would be to remove the backslashes rather than adding additional ones.

Comment: Also, assuming the rest of OP's statements are correct/complete, the primary thing to highlight here is the `(Map<String, Object>)m.get('body');` part. We can't just pluck out arbitrary data from deserialized JSON (as OP is trying to do, but you correct). For others reading this, you need to dig down one level at a time (and you end up doing a _lot of typecasting_ when working with untyped deserialization).

Comment: I didn't say double quotes needed escaping. It's the backslashes that need escaping. In the JSON the value of Failure includes double quotes, so they are escaped with backslashes within the JSON itself. So when you put it into Apex you need to escape those backslashes.

Comment: See here for how double quotes are included in JSON: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15637481/4838305

Comment: If you remove the backslashes then it's no longer valid JSON.

Comment: ah, the thing I think I missed was that `"Failure ...` is the _value_ of `"statusDesc"` rather than its own key:value pair (i.e. some double-serialized JSON, though not quite in the way I first thought).

Comment: @fred above code working but i am trying to replace \ with \\ in my response but getting issue.  string res = replace(response,\,\\);  Unrecognized symbol '\', which is not a valid Apex identifier.

Comment: @Hari you don't need to do any replacing. It's when you declare the string to begin with. E.g. if I wanted to declare the string "C:\Users\Fred" in Apex, I need to do String filePath = 'C:\\Users\\Fred'; \ on its own means something else, \\ means \